# Rails nested routes not filtering

Tags: ruby-on-rails, routes, nested-routes

I have two models: Product and ProductType:

Product:

```
class Product < ActiveRecord::Base
    default_scope :order => 'name'

    has_many :sales

    belongs_to :product_type, :class_name => "ProductType", :foreign_key => "type_id"   
end
```

ProductType:

```
class ProductType < ActiveRecord::Base
    default_scope :order => 'name'

    has_many :products
end
```

In my routes.rb, I have:

```
resources :product_types do
    resources :products
end
```

When I run rake routes, I see that this url exists:

```
        product_type_product GET    /product_types/:product_type_id/products/:id(.:format)               {:controller=>"products", :action=>"show"}
```

The issue I'm having is that when I navigate to: http://localhost:3000/postering_locations/48/users, it will show me the single user I have that has the postering location with id 48. The issue is that it also displays all the other users as well.The same thing happens when I change the 48 to another number that is valid. I feel like it is partially working though because when I exchange it for a number that doesn't exist in the table, I receive a routing error. Any thoughts on how to make /postering_locations/48/users actually show me the users with 48 as their postering_location id?

Also, on my routes.rb, if I still want people to be able to see just /products/, where do I add the resources :products into my routes.rb?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess you should simply edit your controller's action:

```
@products = ProductType.find(params[:product_type_id]).products
```

As for your second question, simply add the mere:

```
resources :products
```

To your routes.rb. In routing the rule is first match first served. But since the nested and unnested url won't match each other, you're fine.

Comment: Hey, sorry... I added the wrong line from the rake routes. Should that :product_type_id be referenced as is or does it need to be in a params[:product_type_id]?

Comment: What happens if I wanted to add other nested resources in? Say for each user I have both a role and a location that a user belongs to. Roles and Locations have many Users. I added nested routes in the same fashion. When I add: @users = Location.find(params[:location_id]).users to my users_controller, it works great when I try to look up users by location. How should I be adding code to the controller so that I can also look up users by role?

Comment: The rule is to post only a question at a time. Moreover, having a brand new question makes the new problem clear, which is not the case now